# Select printer name without showing PrintDialog

Tags: c#, printing, report

I have this code. When I need to print my report, it shows me a Print Dialog. I want to select my print name by code, and print my report without showing `PrintDialog`.

This is my code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing.Printing;

namespace POS.Reports
{
public partial class ProductsReceiptPreview : Form
{
    BindingSource _data;
    string _total, _cashr, _cashc;
    public ProductsReceiptPreview(BindingSource data, string total, 
string cashr, string cashc)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _total = total; _cashr = cashr; _cashc = cashc;
        _data = data;
    }

    private void ProductsReceipt_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataReceiptBindingSource.DataSource = _data;
        Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter[] param = new 
        Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter[]
        {
           new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("ptotal", 
    _total),
            new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("pcashr", 
    _cashr),
             new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("pcashc", 
    _cashc),
            new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter
    ("pdate",DateTime.Now.ToString())
        };
        this.rptProductsReceipt.LocalReport.SetParameters(param);
        this.rptProductsReceipt.RefreshReport();
        this.rptProductsReceipt.ZoomMode = 
    Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ZoomMode.PageWidth;
    }


    private void btnReports_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rptProductsReceipt.PrintDialog();
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i never use your method but i use this

```
rptProductsReceipt.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 0, 0);
```

after using adapter and data table

Comment: this code not work.       

     Error 1 'Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportViewer' does not contain a definition for 'PrintToPrinter' and no extension method 'PrintToPrinter' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportViewer' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\He\Desktop\New folder\POS\POS\Reports\ProductsReceiptPreview.cs 44 32 POS